# Remove workspace white border

Tags: adobe-photoshop, workspace

Since the last Photoshop update, I have a white border around my workspace. I found this very annoying. Do you know how to remove it?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all merely a preference setting...

[image]